# Active Reports 12 - Export RDL report using custom name

Tags: activereports

I wanted to know if it's possible to export a RDL report using a custom name through Javascript, after the report has been rendered using the HTML5 Viewer.

I tried to implement the solutions on these 2 links:

- http://help.grapecity.com/activereports/webhelp/AR12/webframe.html#HTML5WorkingwithViewerUsingJavascript.html
- https://www.grapecity.com/en/blogs/export-using-custom-name-via-html5-viewer

But unfortunately none of them worked. I wanted to export to pdf and csv.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the file name in the custom export call:
here is a sample of script:

```
viewer.export('PDF',  function (uri) {
                var newWin = null;
                try {
                    newWin = window.open(uri);
                } catch (e) { }
                if (!newWin) {
                    window.location = uri;
                }},
                true, {
                FileName: 'AnyValidName.pdf'
            });
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that script unfortunately doesn't work. I noticed that on the official documentation (1st link I provided) under "export" there is a note `Note: In section reports, the export settings are not enabled when exporting files using the rendering extensions. In Page report and RDL report, the export settings are not enabled when exporting files to PDF using the export filter.`. But it's not working for pdf nor csvs.

Comment: that remark in the documentation means the rare case when RDL report is exported via PDF Export filter. by default, HTML5 Viewer uses PDF Rendering Extension for RDL reports where export settings are supported.